# Streaming local videos over the internet

Tags: web-browser, windows-10, streaming, server, ftp

I'd like to share some media with my ex (and possibly other friends) like personal photos, videos. I'm not the kind of guy to put them up for social media.

I have used FTP server before but I wonder if there is a more media focused way to do this (on win 10/11)? One that would simply allow me to check the entire dir trees to share and the user could browse the files in the given tree structure and be able to stream the videos in the browser (or at least download).

I would prefer a notification for file access activity over a log file. The ability to sync watching a video with me, while not a requirement, would be a sweet bonus feature.